# Bulma fluid container but full width on mobile and tablet

Tags: bulma

Is there a "Bulma" way to make a container fluid on desktop and further, but full width on mobile and tablet?

[the offical documentation says:](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/)

> This container is fluid: it will have a 32px gap on either side, on
> any viewport size.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, fluid container has no special behavior in mobile devices and always insert a padding of 32px.

I managed to do what you are looking for by creating a new type of container, that only that only applies the padding in desktop screens, like this:

```css
.container.my-fluid-container {
  max-width: none !important;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container.my-fluid-container {
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-right: 32px;
  }
}
```

And in the HTML:

```html
<div class="container my-fluid-container">
 blah blah
</div>
```